# Keras RNN with LSTM cells for predicting multiple output time series based on multiple intput time series

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I would like to model RNN with LSTM cells in order to predict multiple output time series based on multiple input time series. To be specific, I have 4 output time series, y1[t], y2[t], y3[t], y4[t], each has a length 3,000 (t=0,...,2999). I also have 3 input time series, x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], and each has a length 3,000 sec (t=0,...,2999). The goal is to predict y1[t],.. y4[t] using all the input time series up to this current time point i.e.:

```
  y1[t] = f1(x1[k],x2[k],x3[k], k = 0,...,t)
  y2[t] = f2(x1[k],x2[k],x3[k], k = 0,...,t)
  y3[t] = f3(x1[k],x2[k],x3[k], k = 0,...,t)
  y4[t] = f3(x1[k],x2[k],x3[k], k = 0,...,t)
```

For a model to have a long term memory, I created a stateful RNN model by following. [keras-stateful-lstme](http://philipperemy.github.io/keras-stateful-lstm/). The main difference between my case and [keras-stateful-lstme](http://philipperemy.github.io/keras-stateful-lstm/) is that I have:

- more than 1 output time series
- more than 1 input time series
- the goal is the prediction of continuous time series

My code is running. However the model's prediction result is bad even with a simple data. So I would like to ask you if I am getting anything wrong.

Here is my code with a toy example.

In toy example, our input time series are simple cosign and sign waves:

```
import numpy as np
def random_sample(len_timeseries=3000):
    Nchoice = 600
    x1 = np.cos(np.arange(0,len_timeseries)/float(1.0 + np.random.choice(Nchoice)))
    x2 = np.cos(np.arange(0,len_timeseries)/float(1.0 + np.random.choice(Nchoice)))
    x3 = np.sin(np.arange(0,len_timeseries)/float(1.0 + np.random.choice(Nchoice)))
    x4 = np.sin(np.arange(0,len_timeseries)/float(1.0 + np.random.choice(Nchoice)))
    y1 = np.random.random(len_timeseries)
    y2 = np.random.random(len_timeseries)
    y3 = np.random.random(len_timeseries)
    for t in range(3,len_timeseries):
        ## the output time series depend on input as follows: 
        y1[t] = x1[t-2] 
        y2[t] = x2[t-1]*x3[t-2]
        y3[t] = x4[t-3]
    y = np.array([y1,y2,y3]).T
    X = np.array([x1,x2,x3,x4]).T
    return y, X
def generate_data(Nsequence = 1000):
    X_train = []
    y_train = []
    for isequence in range(Nsequence):
        y, X = random_sample()
        X_train.append(X)
        y_train.append(y)
    return np.array(X_train),np.array(y_train)
```

Please notice that y1 at time point t is simply the value of x1 at t - 2.
Please also notice that y3 at time point t is simply the value of x1 in the two previous step.

Using these functions, I generated 100 sets of time series y1,y2,y3,x1,x2,x3,x4. Half of them go to training data and the remaining half go to testing data.

```
Nsequence = 100
prop = 0.5
Ntrain = Nsequence*prop
X, y = generate_data(Nsequence)
X_train = X[:Ntrain,:,:]
X_test  = X[Ntrain:,:,:]
y_train = y[:Ntrain,:,:]
y_test  = y[Ntrain:,:,:]
```

X, y are both 3 dimensional and each contains:

```
#X.shape = (N sequence, length of time series, N input features)
#y.shape = (N sequence, length of time series, N targets)
print X.shape, y.shape
> (100, 3000, 4) (100, 3000, 3)
```

The example of the time series y1, .. y4 and x1, .., x3 are shown as below:

[image]
[image]

I standardize these data as:

```
def standardize(X_train,stat=None):
    ## X_train is 3 dimentional e.g. (Nsample,len_timeseries, Nfeature)
    ## standardization is done with respect to the 3rd dimention
    if stat is None:
        featmean = np.array([np.nanmean(X_train[:,:,itrain]) for itrain in range(X_train.shape[2])]).reshape(1,1,X_train.shape[2])
        featstd = np.array([np.nanstd(X_train[:,:,itrain]) for itrain in range(X_train.shape[2])]).reshape(1,1,X_train.shape[2])
        stat = {"featmean":featmean,"featstd":featstd}
    else:
        featmean = stat["featmean"]
        featstd = stat["featstd"]
    X_train_s = (X_train - featmean)/featstd
    return X_train_s, stat 

X_train_s, X_stat = standardize(X_train,stat=None)
X_test_s, _ = standardize(X_test,stat=X_stat)
y_train_s, y_stat = standardize(y_train,stat=None)
y_test_s, _ = standardize(y_test,stat=y_stat)
```

**Create a stateful RNN model with 10 LSTM hidden neurons**

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
def create_stateful_model(hidden_neurons):
    # create and fit the LSTM network

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(hidden_neurons, 
                   batch_input_shape=(1, 1, X_train.shape[2]), 
                   return_sequences=False, 
                   stateful=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(y_train.shape[2]))
    model.add(Activation("linear"))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer="rmsprop",metrics=['mean_squared_error'])
    return model
 model = create_stateful_model(10)
```

Now following code is used to train and validate the RNN model:

```
def get_R2(y_pred,y_test):
        ## y_pred_s_batch: (Nsample, len_timeseries, Noutput)
        ## the relative percentage error is computed for each output
        overall_mean = np.nanmean(y_test)
        SSres = np.nanmean( (y_pred - y_test)**2 ,axis=0).mean(axis=0)
        SStot = np.nanmean( (y_test - overall_mean)**2 ,axis=0).mean(axis=0)
        R2 = 1 - SSres / SStot 
        print "<R2 testing> target 1:",R2[0],"target 2:",R2[1],"target 3:",R2[2]
        return R2


def reshape_batch_input(X_t,y_t=None):
    X_t = np.array(X_t).reshape(1,1,len(X_t)) ## (1,1,4) dimention
    if y_t is not None:
        y_t = np.array([y_t]) ## (1,3)
    return X_t,y_t
def fit_stateful(model,X_train,y_train,X_test,y_test,nb_epoch=8):
    '''
    reference: http://philipperemy.github.io/keras-stateful-lstm/

    X_train: (N_time_series, len_time_series, N_features) = (10,000, 3,600 (max), 2), 
    y_train: (N_time_series, len_time_series, N_output) =   (10,000, 3,600 (max), 4)

    '''
    max_len = X_train.shape[1]

    print "X_train.shape(Nsequence =",X_train.shape[0],"len_timeseries =",X_train.shape[1],"Nfeats =",X_train.shape[2],")"
    print "y_train.shape(Nsequence =",y_train.shape[0],"len_timeseries =",y_train.shape[1],"Ntargets =",y_train.shape[2],")"
    print('Train...')
    for epoch in range(nb_epoch):
        print('___________________________________')
        print "epoch", epoch+1, "out of ",nb_epoch
        ## ---------- ##
        ##  training  ##
        ## ---------- ##
        mean_tr_acc = []
        mean_tr_loss = []
        for s in range(X_train.shape[0]):
            for t in range(max_len):
                X_st = X_train[s][t]
                y_st = y_train[s][t]
                if np.any(np.isnan(y_st)):
                    break
                X_st,y_st = reshape_batch_input(X_st,y_st)
                tr_loss, tr_acc = model.train_on_batch(X_st,y_st)
                mean_tr_acc.append(tr_acc)
                mean_tr_loss.append(tr_loss)
            model.reset_states()

        ##print('accuracy training = {}'.format(np.mean(mean_tr_acc)))
        print('<loss (mse) training> {}'.format(np.mean(mean_tr_loss)))
        ## ---------- ##
        ##  testing   ##
        ## ---------- ##
        y_pred = predict_stateful(model,X_test)
        eva =  get_R2(y_pred,y_test)
    return model, eva, y_pred

def predict_stateful(model,X_test):
    y_pred = []
    max_len = X_test.shape[1]
    for s in range(X_test.shape[0]):
        y_s_pred = []
        for t in range(max_len):
            X_st = X_test[s][t]
            if np.any(np.isnan(X_st)):
                ## the rest of y is NA
                y_s_pred.extend([np.NaN]*(max_len-len(y_s_pred)))
                break
            X_st,_ = reshape_batch_input(X_st)
            y_st_pred = model.predict_on_batch(X_st)
            y_s_pred.append(y_st_pred[0].tolist())

        y_pred.append(y_s_pred)
        model.reset_states()

    y_pred = np.array(y_pred)
    return y_pred




  model, train_metric, y_pred = fit_stateful(model,
                                        X_train_s,y_train_s,
                                        X_test_s,y_test_s,nb_epoch=15)
```

The output is the following:

```
X_train.shape(Nsequence = 15 len_timeseries = 3000 Nfeats = 4 )
y_train.shape(Nsequence = 15 len_timeseries = 3000 Ntargets = 3 )
Train...
___________________________________
epoch 1 out of  15
<loss (mse) training> 0.414115458727
<R2 testing> target 1: 0.664464304688 target 2: -0.574523052322 target 3: 0.526447813052
___________________________________
epoch 2 out of  15
<loss (mse) training> 0.394549429417
<R2 testing> target 1: 0.361516087033 target 2: -0.724583671831 target 3: 0.795566178787
___________________________________
epoch 3 out of  15
<loss (mse) training> 0.403199136257
<R2 testing> target 1: 0.09610702779 target 2: -0.468219774909 target 3: 0.69419269042
___________________________________
epoch 4 out of  15
<loss (mse) training> 0.406423777342
<R2 testing> target 1: 0.469149270848 target 2: -0.725592048946 target 3: 0.732963522766
___________________________________
epoch 5 out of  15
<loss (mse) training> 0.408153116703
<R2 testing> target 1: 0.400821776652 target 2: -0.329415365214 target 3: 0.2578432553
___________________________________
epoch 6 out of  15
<loss (mse) training> 0.421062678099
<R2 testing> target 1: -0.100464591586 target 2: -0.232403824523 target 3: 0.570606489959
___________________________________
epoch 7 out of  15
<loss (mse) training> 0.417774856091
<R2 testing> target 1: 0.320094445321 target 2: -0.606375769083 target 3: 0.349876223119
___________________________________
epoch 8 out of  15
<loss (mse) training> 0.427440851927
<R2 testing> target 1: 0.489543715713 target 2: -0.445328806611 target 3: 0.236463139804
___________________________________
epoch 9 out of  15
<loss (mse) training> 0.422931671143
<R2 testing> target 1: -0.31006468223 target 2: -0.322621276474 target 3: 0.122573123871
___________________________________
epoch 10 out of  15
<loss (mse) training> 0.43609803915
<R2 testing> target 1: 0.459111316554 target 2: -0.313382405804 target 3: 0.636854743292
___________________________________
epoch 11 out of  15
<loss (mse) training> 0.433844655752
<R2 testing> target 1: -0.0161015052703 target 2: -0.237462995323 target 3: 0.271788109459
___________________________________
epoch 12 out of  15
<loss (mse) training> 0.437297314405
<R2 testing> target 1: -0.493665758658 target 2: -0.234236263092 target 3: 0.047264439493
___________________________________
epoch 13 out of  15
<loss (mse) training> 0.470605045557
<R2 testing> target 1: 0.144443089961 target 2: -0.333210874982 target 3: -0.00432615142135
___________________________________
epoch 14 out of  15
<loss (mse) training> 0.444566756487
<R2 testing> target 1: -0.053982119103 target 2: -0.0676577449316 target 3: -0.12678037186
___________________________________
epoch 15 out of  15
<loss (mse) training> 0.482106208801
<R2 testing> target 1: 0.208482181828 target 2: -0.402982670798 target 3: 0.366757778713
```

As you can see, the training loss is NOT decreasing!!

As the target time series 1 and 3 have very simple relations with the input time series (y1[t] = x1[t-2] , y3[t] = x4[t-3]), I would expect perfect prediction performance. However, testing R2 at every epoch shows that that is not the case. R2 at the final epoch is just about 0.2 and 0.36. Clearly, the algorithm is not converging. I am very puzzled with this result. Please do let me know what I am missing, and why the algorithm is not converging.

Comment: Usually when this type of thing happens, there's a problem with the hyperparameters. Have you considered doing some hyperparameter optimization via the `hyperopt` package, or the `hyperas` wrapper?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Initial note.** If time series were short (for example T = 30), we wouldn't need stateful LSTM and classic LSTM would work well.
In OP question, time series lengths are T=3000, so learning can be very slow with classic LSTM. Learning will be improved by cutting the time series into pieces and using stateful LSTM.

**Stateful mode with N=batch_size.**
Stateful models are tricky with Keras, because you need to be careful on how you cut time series and select batch size. In OP question, sample size is N=100. Since we can accept to train model with batch of one hundred (it is not a large number), we will select batch_size=100.

Selecting batch_size=N simplifies the training because you do not need to reset states inside epochs (so no need to write a callback on_batch_begin).

It remains the question of cutting the time series. Cutting is a little technical, so I wrote a wrapper function working in all cases.

```
def stateful_cut(arr, batch_size, T_after_cut):
    if len(arr.shape) != 3:
        # N: Independent sample size,
        # T: Time length,
        # m: Dimension
        print("ERROR: please format arr as a (N, T, m) array.")

    N = arr.shape[0]
    T = arr.shape[1]

    # We need T_after_cut * nb_cuts = T
    nb_cuts = int(T / T_after_cut)
    if nb_cuts * T_after_cut != T:
        print("ERROR: T_after_cut must divide T")

    # We need batch_size * nb_reset = N
    # If nb_reset = 1, we only reset after the whole epoch, so no need to reset
    nb_reset = int(N / batch_size)
    if nb_reset * batch_size != N:
        print("ERROR: batch_size must divide N")

    # Cutting (technical)
    cut1 = np.split(arr, nb_reset, axis=0)
    cut2 = [np.split(x, nb_cuts, axis=1) for x in cut1]
    cut3 = [np.concatenate(x) for x in cut2]
    cut4 = np.concatenate(cut3)
    return(cut4)
```

From now, it become easy to train the model. Since the OP example is very simple, we do not need additional preprocessing or regularization. I describe how to proceed step by step *(for the impatient, whole self-contained code is available at the very end of this post).*

First we load data and reshape it with wrapper function.

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, TimeDistributed
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

##
# Data
##
N = X_train.shape[0] # size of samples
T = X_train.shape[1] # length of each time series
batch_size = N # number of time series considered together: batch_size | N
T_after_cut = 100 # length of each cut part of the time series: T_after_cut | T
dim_in = X_train.shape[2] # dimension of input time series
dim_out = y_train.shape[2] # dimension of output time series

inputs, outputs, inputs_test, outputs_test = \
  [stateful_cut(arr, batch_size, T_after_cut) for arr in \
  [X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test]]
```

Then we compile a model with 4 inputs, 3 outputs, and 1 hidden layer containing 10 nodes.

```
##
# Model
##
nb_units = 10

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(batch_input_shape=(batch_size, None, dim_in),
               return_sequences=True, units=nb_units, stateful=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(activation='linear', units=dim_out)))
model.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = 'rmsprop')
```

We train the model without resetting states. We can do it only because we have selected batch_size = N.

```
##
# Training
##
epochs = 100

nb_reset = int(N / batch_size)
if nb_reset > 1:
    print("ERROR: We need to reset states when batch_size < N")

# When nb_reset = 1, we do not need to reinitialize states
history = model.fit(inputs, outputs, epochs = epochs, 
                    batch_size = batch_size, shuffle=False,
                    validation_data=(inputs_test, outputs_test))
```

We get evolution of training/test loss as follows:

[image: training and test loss decreasing as a function of epochs as expected]

Now, we define a 'mime model' which is stateless but containing our stateful weights. [Why like this? Prediction with stateful model through model.predict needs a complete batch in Keras, but we may not have a complete batch to predict...]

```
## Mime model which is stateless but containing stateful weights
model_stateless = Sequential()
model_stateless.add(LSTM(input_shape=(None, dim_in),
               return_sequences=True, units=nb_units))
model_stateless.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(activation='linear', units=dim_out)))
model_stateless.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = 'rmsprop')
model_stateless.set_weights(model.get_weights())
```

Finally, we can show our incredible predictions on our long time series y1, y2 and y3 (blue for true output ; orange for predicted outputs):

*For y1:*
[image: Prediction for y1]

*For y2:*
[image: Prediction for y2]

*For y3:*
[image: Prediction for y3]

**Conclusion**: It works almost perfectly, unless for the 2-3 first dates where the series is unpredictable by definition. We do not observe any burst when going from one batch for the next batch.

**Much more** When N is large, we would like to select batch_size | N with batch_size < N. I have written full code in https://github.com/ahstat/deep-learning/blob/master/rnn/4_lagging_and_stateful.py (Part C and D). This github path also shows efficiency of classic LSTM for short time series (Part A), and inefficiency for long time series (Part B). I've written a blog post detailing how to use Keras for time series predictions here: https://ahstat.github.io/RNN-Keras-time-series/ .

**Complete self-contained code**

```
################
# Code from OP #
################
import numpy as np
def random_sample(len_timeseries=3000):
    Nchoice = 600
    x1 = np.cos(np.arange(0,len_timeseries)/float(1.0 + np.random.choice(Nchoice)))
    x2 = np.cos(np.arange(0,len_timeseries)/float(1.0 + np.random.choice(Nchoice)))
    x3 = np.sin(np.arange(0,len_timeseries)/float(1.0 + np.random.choice(Nchoice)))
    x4 = np.sin(np.arange(0,len_timeseries)/float(1.0 + np.random.choice(Nchoice)))
    y1 = np.random.random(len_timeseries)
    y2 = np.random.random(len_timeseries)
    y3 = np.random.random(len_timeseries)
    for t in range(3,len_timeseries):
        ## the output time series depend on input as follows: 
        y1[t] = x1[t-2] 
        y2[t] = x2[t-1]*x3[t-2]
        y3[t] = x4[t-3]
    y = np.array([y1,y2,y3]).T
    X = np.array([x1,x2,x3,x4]).T
    return y, X
def generate_data(Nsequence = 1000):
    X_train = []
    y_train = []
    for isequence in range(Nsequence):
        y, X = random_sample()
        X_train.append(X)
        y_train.append(y)
    return np.array(X_train),np.array(y_train)

Nsequence = 100
prop = 0.5
Ntrain = int(Nsequence*prop)
X, y = generate_data(Nsequence)
X_train = X[:Ntrain,:,:]
X_test  = X[Ntrain:,:,:]
y_train = y[:Ntrain,:,:]
y_test  = y[Ntrain:,:,:] 

#X.shape = (N sequence, length of time series, N input features)
#y.shape = (N sequence, length of time series, N targets)
print(X.shape, y.shape)
# (100, 3000, 4) (100, 3000, 3)

####################
# Cutting function #
####################
def stateful_cut(arr, batch_size, T_after_cut):
    if len(arr.shape) != 3:
        # N: Independent sample size,
        # T: Time length,
        # m: Dimension
        print("ERROR: please format arr as a (N, T, m) array.")

    N = arr.shape[0]
    T = arr.shape[1]

    # We need T_after_cut * nb_cuts = T
    nb_cuts = int(T / T_after_cut)
    if nb_cuts * T_after_cut != T:
        print("ERROR: T_after_cut must divide T")

    # We need batch_size * nb_reset = N
    # If nb_reset = 1, we only reset after the whole epoch, so no need to reset
    nb_reset = int(N / batch_size)
    if nb_reset * batch_size != N:
        print("ERROR: batch_size must divide N")

    # Cutting (technical)
    cut1 = np.split(arr, nb_reset, axis=0)
    cut2 = [np.split(x, nb_cuts, axis=1) for x in cut1]
    cut3 = [np.concatenate(x) for x in cut2]
    cut4 = np.concatenate(cut3)
    return(cut4)

#############
# Main code #
#############
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, TimeDistributed
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

##
# Data
##
N = X_train.shape[0] # size of samples
T = X_train.shape[1] # length of each time series
batch_size = N # number of time series considered together: batch_size | N
T_after_cut = 100 # length of each cut part of the time series: T_after_cut | T
dim_in = X_train.shape[2] # dimension of input time series
dim_out = y_train.shape[2] # dimension of output time series

inputs, outputs, inputs_test, outputs_test = \
  [stateful_cut(arr, batch_size, T_after_cut) for arr in \
  [X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test]]

##
# Model
##
nb_units = 10

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(batch_input_shape=(batch_size, None, dim_in),
               return_sequences=True, units=nb_units, stateful=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(activation='linear', units=dim_out)))
model.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = 'rmsprop')

##
# Training
##
epochs = 100

nb_reset = int(N / batch_size)
if nb_reset > 1:
    print("ERROR: We need to reset states when batch_size < N")

# When nb_reset = 1, we do not need to reinitialize states
history = model.fit(inputs, outputs, epochs = epochs, 
                    batch_size = batch_size, shuffle=False,
                    validation_data=(inputs_test, outputs_test))

def plotting(history):
    plt.plot(history.history['loss'], color = "red")
    plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], color = "blue")
    red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='Training')
    blue_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='blue', label='Test')
    plt.legend(handles=[red_patch, blue_patch])
    plt.xlabel('Epochs')
    plt.ylabel('MSE loss')
    plt.show()

plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
plotting(history) # Evolution of training/test loss

##
# Visual checking for a time series
##
## Mime model which is stateless but containing stateful weights
model_stateless = Sequential()
model_stateless.add(LSTM(input_shape=(None, dim_in),
               return_sequences=True, units=nb_units))
model_stateless.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(activation='linear', units=dim_out)))
model_stateless.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = 'rmsprop')
model_stateless.set_weights(model.get_weights())

## Prediction of a new set
i = 0 # time series selected (between 0 and N-1)
x = X_train[i]
y = y_train[i]
y_hat = model_stateless.predict(np.array([x]))[0]

for dim in range(3): # dim = 0 for y1 ; dim = 1 for y2 ; dim = 2 for y3.
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
    plt.plot(range(T), y[:,dim])
    plt.plot(range(T), y_hat[:,dim])
    plt.show()

## Conclusion: works almost perfectly.
```

Comment: I'm working on a similar problem. I have sales of a bunch of items ( more than 5000 items) and want to predict sales in the future. In my case time series will not have the same length ( items that are being sold only from a certain date) . This solution could work in this situation?

Comment: This solution can work by feeding time-series of unequal length ; I would begin with simpler models though, and then try to understand whether RNN models can capture more information from data

Comment: @ahstat Thank you very much for the very detailed code. I have been searching a lot for this (data prep and prediction). Can I use many time series of different sequence length to train with stateful ?  ( I was thinking, I can use pad, mask to make the length same , for the shorter sequences, am I right ?). 2.) Also, could you please tell me how will get the state of the previous batch, when we are using stateless for prediction

Comment: @ahstat Thank you for your work! Could you please elaborate on how this can be used with time-series of unequal length? My X.shape is (100, different-lenghts, 39) .. basically my input sequences have all different length.. (and my output too)